# Unable to move the player to the touch point Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want my player to be moved along with my finger, but for some reason it isnt working. PFB the code, the player stays still with no movement:

Below method is called in update method:

```
void TouchMovement()
{
    if (isMoving)
        currentDistanceToTouchPos = (_touchPosition - transform.position).magnitude;
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        
        if (touch.phase == UnityEngine.TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            previousDistanceToTouchPos = 0;
            currentDistanceToTouchPos = 0;
            isMoving = true;
            _touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
            _touchPosition.z = 0;
            whereToMove = (_touchPosition - transform.position).normalized;
            _rb.velocity = new Vector2(whereToMove.x * _speed, whereToMove.y * _speed); 
        }

        if (currentDistanceToTouchPos > previousDistanceToTouchPos)
        { 
            isMoving=false;
            _rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        }

        if (isMoving)
            previousDistanceToTouchPos = (_touchPosition - transform.position).magnitude;
    }
}
```

Tried with the above mentioned code but no progress since over a week now. Please help

Comment: how do you think in this if (currentDistanceToTouchPos > previousDistanceToTouchPos) is going to happen? you never update currentdistance

Comment: The usage of ScreenToWorldPoint is incorrect (it requires a Vector3, not a Vector2).  Only use that function if you know how far from the camera into the world you want the point to be.  If you do not know how far from the camera the point will be, use ScreenPointToRay and get the hit point using a raycast.

Comment: @hijinxbassist in case where this is an orthographic 2D camera it can be legit though since in that scenario the distance to camera doesn't matter ... as OP only uses `Vector2` I would assume that' the case here

Comment: In general to void hickups with overshooting etc it might be better to use `MovePosition` in `FixedddUpdate` and `Vector2.MoveTowards` instead of dealing with velocities ... and then for the check rather use e.g. `if(rb.position != _touchPosition)` though `MoveTowards` would make that check quite redundant

Comment: @BugFinder at the very beginning the currentdistance is calculated

Comment: @Ashok 22 hours ago before it was edited, it was not included in the code section.. so got missed.. these things matter